# SQL Syntax question

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

What does the following statement mean?  Is it an equivalent for `TOP`?

```
select +10 as ContentID
```

Comment: Thanks folks, the + was throwing me for some reason.

Comment: Is it maybe the Unary Plus operator?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174362.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it simply returns a result set with one row and one column (named ContentID), and that column contains the integer number 10.

Comment: Dude! Snap! That's uncanny, that is.

Answer (score 5):

No, it will simply return a record set with one record and one field.
The field will be named ContentId and it will contain "10" (probably as an int)

Comment: Wow, maybe we're twins separated at birth?  Almost exactly the same words.

Comment: Well my Mom - maysherestinpeace - spent a couple of years in New York, between 1948 and '53, maybe there's something she never told us . . . and we're both developers! This MUST be more than coincidence!